# How do I extract either second occurrence of repeated subject ID or first if not repeated?

Tags: r

I am looking to extract **the second occurrence of a subject ID** (the entire row of their data) *OR* **the first if the row is not repeated.**

These data are from repeated visits and we are interested in only subjects from last-non-missing data, meaning that either the subject has "screening" information and no "injection" or they have both. This is how we define "baseline." If subject has both, we *only* want to retain the row of data with the injection (last data before treatment), if only screening then screening (that's then the last data before treatment and will equal baseline).

*Here's some data*:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4),
                  visit = c('screening', 'screening', 'injection', 'screening', 
'injection', 'screening'),
                  var2 = c(1, 6, 3, 12, 0, 2))
```

**What I have attempted:**

- Separating out and re-merging data frames that contain the two qualifiers for these subjects. But when I do so, the columns just get duplicated, producing a wide instead of long dataset (when they obviously match by the exact same ID).
- Using a filter in dplyr with multiple conditions, but it only catches those with screening because that always comes first for the repeated subjects.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

use `slice_tail()`

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice_tail()

#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   ID [4]
#>      ID visit      var2
#>   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1     1 screening     1
#> 2     2 injection     3
#> 3     3 injection     0
#> 4     4 screening     2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Concise answer! Great!

Answer (score 4):

Groupwise conditions can be coded easily with dplyr. This will always extract the last row for each ID.

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(row_number() == n())
```

If you want to always extract the first or second row, use `min()` on top of the code above.

```r
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(row_number() == min(n(), 2))
```

In both cases, the result is the filtered data formatted as a tibble

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   ID [4]
     ID visit      var2
  <dbl> <fct>     <dbl>
1     1 screening     1
2     2 injection     3
3     3 injection     0
4     4 screening     2
```

Comment: Won't work if a subject is repeated more than 2 rows. OP needs specifically the second one not the latest one.

Answer (score 2):

A base R option with `subset` + `ave` + `match`

```
subset(
    df1,
    !!ave(match(visit, c("screening", "injection")), ID, FUN = function(x) x == length(x))
)
```

gives

```
  ID     visit var2
1  1 screening    1
3  2 injection    3
5  3 injection    0
6  4 screening    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `duplicated` from `base R`

```
subset(df1, !duplicated(ID, fromLast = TRUE))
  ID     visit var2
1  1 screening    1
3  2 injection    3
5  3 injection    0
6  4 screening    2
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the new pipe below so replace `|>` with `%>%` if you prefer or can only use the old pipe (from magrittr rather than base). But essentially I've addressed these conditions separately. First I used `unique()` to remove duplicate rows. Then I've created additional indicators to select the second row with the same ID where one exists (now that there are no duplicate rows).

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4),
                  visit = c('screening', 'screening', 'injection', 'screening', 
                            'injection', 'screening'),
                  var2 = c(1, 6, 3, 12, 0, 2))

df1 |> 
# Remove exact duplicate rows
  unique() |> 
  group_by(ID) |> 
  # Create two new indicators, one which shows the row number for the group (i.e first, second, ...)
  # The second indicator shows the total number of duplicate entries for the ID
  mutate(row_number_by_id = row_number(), count = n()) |> 
  # Select only the rows that appear second or that only have one entry for the ID
  filter(count == 1 | row_number_by_id == 2)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#> # Groups:   ID [4]
#>      ID visit      var2 row_number_by_id count
#>   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>            <int> <int>
#> 1     1 screening     1                1     1
#> 2     2 injection     3                2     2
#> 3     3 injection     0                2     2
#> 4     4 screening     2                1     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `min()` function to refer to the alphabetical order of the visit string.

```
> df1 %>% filter(visit == "screening" || visit == "injection") %>%
group_by(ID) %>% summarise(min(visit))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     ID `min(visit)`
  <dbl> <chr>       
1     1 screening   
2     2 injection   
3     3 injection   
4     4 screening
```

See other summarise function [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html?q=summar).

Or using the `row_number()`

```
df1 %>% filter(visit == "screening" || visit == "injection") %>%
group_by(ID) %>% filter(row_number() == max(row_number()))
```

If you have another column that can identify the order of these rows, I would suggest you use that one.